# Alt + Enter doesn't use appropriate quick fix in Resharper

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I worked with Resharper 5 before and when I have a problem in code (for example unsuitable space around a parentheses), I used <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and Resharper fixed the problem. But in V6, this doesn't fix the problem, it generate a supress statement! What should I do?

Here is more detail:

1- I have this line in my code:

```
      if (this.RequestClose!= null)
```

Resharper draw a blue line under it and warn that the space around != is not correct.
In Resharper 5, I could press Alt+Entyer two times to fix the spacing problem. In Resharper 6, if I press Alt + Enter two times on this line, nothing happens.

2- I have this line in my code:

```
 var view = new AddressDetailView();
 view.DataContext = viewModel;
```

Resharper suggests using object initializer, but pressing Alt+Enter twice doesn't fix it.

Comment: Go to the Resharper website, and ask your question there.. I don't think this is the appropriate place for this => not programming related

Comment: Aww, come on @Pbirkoff. Resharper not programming related? How's that then? FAQ explicitly allows questions on "software tools commonly used by programmers".

Comment: We need *much* more detail than is currently in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resharper 6.1 solved this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually look at the menu item you're selecting? (I'm guessing not, since your question includes no mention of what's in the menu.) Alt+Enter brings up a pop-up menu, you know. By pressing Alt+Enter twice, you're just selecting the first item in that menu.

ReSharper 6 has new features, therefore it has more options in the list, therefore the order is sometimes different. The quick fixes are almost certainly still working; it's just that the first quick-fix in the list isn't always the same one as in R#5.

The solution is simple: read what's on the screen before you select it. If the quick-fix you want isn't the first in the list, then cursor to the one you want before you hit Enter.

(There's never been a ReSharper version where it's safe to always accept the first item in the menu -- the options change depending on whether R#'s background scanning has completed yet or not. If you've been blindly accepting the first item every time, I'm surprised you haven't gotten bitten before now.)

Comment: Thanks for reply. In most cases the quick fix works (for example for when the problem is extra space around = ). In R6 this doesn't work. As explained in the question for the line that I have and the spacing around != is not right, pressing Alt+Enter twice doesn't work (it does nothing). I need to select the fix spacing from the context menu. How can I reorder the quick fixes for a case so the first one for spacing problems became the default one?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't reorder the quick-fixes. You just need to look at the screen to see which one you're about to select. But as I said, that's *always been the case.*

Comment: As you know, you can use CTRL+E CTRL+F to do code clean up for a file. In previous version, when I pressed Alt+Enter, Resharper did the same code cleaning ing on the current line. (Mainly doing quick fix for basic items such as spaces and naming conventions (local name should starts with lower case and so on)). New version of ReSharper doesn't do this. (If you have access to Resharper 5.1 by any chance, you may test it)

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any way to fix this problem and decided to use R# 5.1 with Style cope instead.

Comment: Style Cop is available for Resharper 6 also.

Comment: It makes the problem that I mentioned in original question.